# Linear Algebra-Projection onto set?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was re-doing an exam question that I missed and was hoping someone could review my steps and see where I went wrong?

Let f and g be in the space C[-$\pi$,$\pi$] and the inner product defined as $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)g(x)dx$

And the set S=$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)},\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt(\pi)}\right\}$

Find the $\operatorname{proj}_{s}f$

Work here: [image]

Comment: Taking inner product is the definition of projection, you found orthogonal part to $S$.

Comment: Yea.. I figured out my mistake... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to project $(x-1)$ onto $S$.

You have computed the projection to be

$$\left(-\sqrt{2\pi} \right)\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)+\left(2\sqrt{\pi} \right)\left( \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right).$$

Do not subtract it from $x-1$.

Comment: Oh.. Really? Why don't I need to use the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is used to find an orthonormal basis. Here we are given an orthonormal basis, we just have to project onto it.

Comment: Haha yea I read your response a couple of times and figured it out.. Wow, I feel so dumb for how long I spent trying to figure that out... The question wasn't to convert to an orthogonal basis.. Just project f onto the set. Thanks. I don't even want to say how many times I re-did those integrals.

Comment: Also, was that you who edited my markdown to make the brackets bigger? How did you do it?

Comment: Use \left{ and \right}

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Do I need to mark this as solved or anything?

Comment: If you think the answer is good enough and helpful then accept and upvote. suppose not, then wait for another answer that is more awesome and accept that one. You can upvote multiple post but you can only accept one.